# How to use google+ sample?

Tags: android, google-plus

I downloaded google+ sample.

But a error occured in source.

```
mPlusClient.loadPeople(LoginGLActivity.this, Person.Collection.VISIBLE);
```

Why printed red line on 'Person.Collection.VISIBLE' ?

Comment: Did you import the google play services lib project into your Eclipse environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Person.Collection.VISIBLE is valid in Google-play-service froyo(Rev. 12).

There are changes in Class "Person" in Google-play-service Rev. 13. Use this, instead:

```
mPlusClient.loadVisiblePeople(NewLoginActivity.this,null)
```